# What search algorithm is used by Java to search the String pool for already present Strings for String interning?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, jvm

I have already read the following posts:

1. [How does the JVM check if a string is already in the string
   pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247935/how-does-the-jvm-check-if-a-string-is-already-in-the-string-pool)
2. [How does Java implement string pooling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498336/how-does-java-implement-string-pooling)

Neither of them mentions the search algorithm that is used by the JVM to search for String literals that have previously been created and exist in the so-called "String pool."

Comment: Implementation-defined. Which implementation?

Comment: You will need to refer to a specific implementation of the JVM, there are multiple popular ones ([List of Java virtual machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines)). The one you get from Oracles official site as standard download is called [HotSpot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot).

Comment: Hash table in HotSpot JVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of String pool is done in native language i.e. **c/c++** using Java Native Interface (JNI) and shared libraries
[You can read how to do this here](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/native1.1/stepbystep/_library.html)
<del>As per me, string pool has been implemented using `trie` data-structure</del>
[You can read about tries here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/)

`Trie` will take O(l) ,where l is length of the requested string, time to search the string pool.

**UPD1:** The String pool has been implemented as a hash-table and the memory allocation to the pool can be updated using `-XX:StringTableSize=<value>` 
Though i feel use of `trie` would have been better as `trie` would have accommodated more number of strings in the same space to that of a `hash-table`

Comment: Why do you think it is `Trie`? Looks like some hash table is better solution.

Comment: @talex the disadvantage of HotSpot’s string pool hash table is its fixed size, so there are lots of collision if the size has been exceeded, especially prior to Java 7, update 40, when the default size was as small as 1,023 (now its ~60,000). But the obvious disadvantage of the `Tri` as shown in that link is its dependency on the alphabet size, as a `char` can have 65536 different values…