# What's the searching algorithm does Java String Pool implemented

Tags: java

String in Java is Immutable. When we use String literal (double quotes) to create a String, it first looks for String with same value in the String pool.

```
String first = "abc";
```

My question is what's the searching algorithm does the JVM searches for "abc"? It just loop the whole String Pool values?

Comment: OP wants to know not just the concept of String pool but the actual searching algorithm. Check this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498461/10317684](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498461/10317684). Short answer would be it depends but most likely hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It just loop the whole String Pool values?

No.

My understanding is that the string pool is a form of hashtable implemented in native code.

So the search algorithm is a hashtable algorithm.  Under normal circumstances, interning a string is an amortized `O(1)` operation.

(The linked Q&A includes some links to the C++ source code.)