# determining which existing string to point to on creation of new string

Tags: java, string, pointers

in java if you define a string which containes a array of char that already exist it will be bount to the same refrence which i assumed it scanned the memory from bottom to top to search but on further inspection its the first string initiated with that string even if that string has a "higher" adress so i wondered how the java interperter searches for existing strings
i checked the variable's adress using

```
System.identityHashCode()
```

and used a basic string for testing like
**"hello"**

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498336/how-does-java-implement-string-pooling

Comment: i couldnt see the answer to this exact question my question is assuming i have a "hello" string in memory at x adress and i have a "hello" in memory in a diffrent address lets call it y how would java decide which one to use if i create a new hello stirng without the new key word

Comment: This depends of the JVM implementation, you need to check JVM specs you are using.